# Will polymer build more ready-use components?

Tags: polymer

I am going to port our windows-based Customer Management software to Web-based. I find polymer may be a choice.

However, for our usage, we can't find polymer component has table-view, drop-down menu(aka. the "select" element in html), date-picker, tree list.

Will polymer add these components later? Or these components will not be the target?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer is just primarily a polyfill library that helps enabling HTML 5 Web Components in browsers that don't support them by themselves.

Web Components can be written by any developer, so you might need to develop some controls on your own especially the table view one. I'd guess you'll find most of the others mentioned in your question implemented one way or another. You should check out some of the WebComponents collection pages:

- http://customelements.io/
- http://component.kitchen/
- http://bower.io/search/?q=web-components

For your table view control: I had a similar problem couple of years ago and had to implement my own solution. Maybe you can find a regular HTML library that supports table views and make it a (Polymer) Web Component by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me clear about the role of the polymer. I follow your web link and find a table view polymer component in the http://customelements.io/